# Icon is not showing up on the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason the icons are not showing up on the action bar even though everything seems correct to me. If I press the menu button on my phone I do get the menu items as text which is fine. However, I have a search icon that I want to display on the action bar but it doesn't appear for some reason. Here is a snippet of the code that seems relevant.

**OnCreate**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
        actionBar.setSubtitle("subtitle");
        actionBar.setTitle("title");
    }
```

**Option Menu**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Menu XML**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ammar.customlistview1.app.MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Action Search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />

</menu>
```

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Let me know if you need any further details, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually use the current `ActionBar` without any `Support Library` to add item to it, which allow you to get the ActionBar on API level 11 or higher and create a menu ([first snippet code from the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)).

Therefore, the `showAsAction` attribute does not need to be with a custom prefix like you do with the `Support Library` ([third snippet code from the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)). Just call the Android default library as follows:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Also you have to remove `xmlns:context`, `xmlns:app` and `xmlns:tools` attributes, they are useless in your menu file.

Comment: Are you saying I should be using `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `app:showAsAction="always"`? That throws an error.

Comment: Yes @Ammar. What kind of error? Does your class extends `Activity` and not `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: I have extends `Activity` since I am using a custom listview there. If I change it to `ActionBarActivity` then I get errors.

Comment: No, no @Ammar, don't change this extension. You have the right one. It was to be sure.

Comment: so with this line `ActionBar actionBar = ActionBarActivity();` I get this ... can't resolve method "ActionBarActivity"

Comment: You have nothing to change @Ammar, except the `android:showAsAction` attribute. I'll rewrite my answer, because I think it has perturbed you ;)

Comment: I am waiting for the update of your answer and thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that the library AppCompat is removed from your project (Click right on project > Properties > Android > Library (at the bottom) > remove AppCompat), also make that all your styles uses `Theme.Holo.Light` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. @Ammar

Comment: I have android studio so I can't see the project properties by following the above

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio but it might be File > Project Structure > Libraries (or Modules). Also take a look on your Gradle, you should remove `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+`

Answer (score 0):

HI just use bellow menu xml file and try

tell me if you got any error

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Action Search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```